# telegram api Auth key generation

Tags: telegram, telethon

I'm reading the telegram API documentation ([Auth key generation example](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/samples-auth_key)), but I don't quite understand what the `N` in `(unixtime() << 32) + (N*4)` means.
If you know, please let me know, thanks a lot.

In the Telethon source code (`nanoseconds << 2`), it seems that `nanoseconds` here is N, is that correct?

Comment: Please specify in greater detail *where* you found the cited part in the documentation.

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/samples-auth_key     ===>>>    1) Client sends query to server

Comment: When you are asked for further information, then please don't add a comment to answer, but *edit* the question instead. I did it for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

The link under "as specified [here](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/description#message-identifier-msg-id)" in the [Auth key generation example](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/samples-auth_key) contains the explanation; specifically "*are divisible by 4*".

> A (time-dependent) 64-bit number used uniquely to identify a message within a session. Client message identifiers are divisible by 4, server message identifiers modulo 4 yield 1 if the message is a response to a client message, and 3 otherwise. Client message identifiers must increase monotonically (within a single session), the same as server message identifiers, and must approximately equal unixtime*2^32. This way, a message identifier points to the approximate moment in time the message was created. A message is rejected over 300 seconds after it is created or 30 seconds before it is created (this is needed to protect from replay attacks). In this situation, it must be re-sent with a different identifier (or placed in a container with a higher identifier). The identifier of a message container must be strictly greater than those of its nested messages.

Comment: Yes, I've looked here, but I don't understand N*4 very well

Comment: Multiplying N by 4 means it will guarantee it's evenly divisible by 4.